# Flutter Could not find the correct Provider<LocationProvider> above this Consumer<LocationProvider> Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am trying to make a map and button below the map which calls ModalBottomSheetBar with a form inside it but i am getting an error, anyone know what is the problem in the below code ?

It gives  "Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget", I don't get the error showed in logs

```
  RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 370,
                        child: Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: Consumer<LocationProvider>(
                              builder: (context, locationProvider, _) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 16.0,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Form(
                                    key: _deliveryAddressFormKey,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          height: 50,
                                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Expanded(
                                                  flex: 3,
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      S.S
                                                          .of(context)
                                                          .provide_your_current_location,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 15, left: 15),
                                                  child: widget
                                                          .resultCardConfirmWidget ??
                                                      RaisedButton(
                                                          elevation: 2,
                                                          highlightElevation: 2,
                                                          splashColor:
                                                              Theme.of(context)
                                                                  .accentColor,
                                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                                              .primaryColor,
                                                          colorBrightness:
                                                              Brightness.light,
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            _submit();
                                                          },
                                                          child: Text(S.S
                                                              .of(context)
                                                              .save)),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Flexible(
                                                flex: 2,
                                                child: Container(
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.person_pin_circle,
                                                    color: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .accentColor,
                                                    size: 35,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                child: Flexible(
                                                  flex: 15,
                                                  child: FutureLoadingBuilder<
                                                          String>(
                                                      future: getAddress(
                                                          locationProvider
                                                              .lastIdleLocation),
                                                      mutable: true,
                                                      loadingIndicator: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      builder: (context, address) {
                                                        _address = address;
                                                        return Text(
                                                          address ??
                                                              S.S
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                                  .unnamed_place,
                                                          overflow:
                                                              TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 16),
                                                          maxLines: 1,
                                                        );
                                                      }),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Visibility(
                                          visible: false,
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 20),
                                            child: new TextFormField(
                                              enabled: false,
                                              //  initialValue: _address.isEmpty ? "" : _address,
                                              onSaved: (input) =>
                                                  address.address = input,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 8.0,
                                              bottom: 8.0,
                                              left: 8.0,
                                              right: 8.0),
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            onSaved: (input) =>
                                                address.description = input,
                                            validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                                                ? S.S
                                                    .of(context)
                                                    .should_be_more_than_3_letters
                                                : null,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .accentColor),
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .focusColor
                                                      .withOpacity(0.7)),
                                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.streetview,
                                                  size: 30,
                                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .accentColor),
                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .focusColor
                                                          .withOpacity(0.2))),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .focusColor
                                                          .withOpacity(0.5))),
                                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .accentColor
                                                          .withOpacity(0.2))),
                                              hintText: S.S.of(context).description,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 8.0),
                                                child: Container(
                                                  width: 150,
                                                  child: TextFormField(
                                                    initialValue: address
                                                                .description
                                                                ?.isNotEmpty ??
                                                            false
                                                        ? address.description
                                                        : null,
                                                    validator: (input) =>
                                                        input.trim().length == 0
                                                            ? S.S
                                                                .of(context)
                                                                .should_not_be_empty
                                                            : null,
                                                    onSaved: (input) =>
                                                        address.buildingNo = input,
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    keyboardType:
                                                        TextInputType.number,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                                              .accentColor),
                                                      contentPadding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                                              .focusColor
                                                              .withOpacity(0.7)),
                                                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                                                          Icons.location_city,
                                                          size: 30,
                                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                                              .accentColor),
                                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                              color:
                                                                  Theme.of(context)
                                                                      .focusColor
                                                                      .withOpacity(
                                                                          0.2))),
                                                      focusedBorder:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                  color: Theme.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .focusColor
                                                                      .withOpacity(
                                                                          0.5))),
                                                      enabledBorder:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                  color: Theme.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .accentColor
                                                                      .withOpacity(
                                                                          0.2))),
                                                      hintText: S.S
                                                          .of(context)
                                                          .buildingNo,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: 150,
                                                child: TextFormField(
                                                  initialValue: address.description
                                                              ?.isNotEmpty ??
                                                          false
                                                      ? address.description
                                                      : null,
                                                  onSaved: (input) =>
                                                      address.aptNo = input,
                                                  validator: (input) =>
                                                      input.length == 0
                                                          ? S.S
                                                              .of(context)
                                                              .should_not_be_empty
                                                          : null,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  keyboardType:
                                                      TextInputType.number,
                                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                                            .accentColor),
                                                    contentPadding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                                            .focusColor
                                                            .withOpacity(0.7)),
                                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.domain,
                                                        size: 30,
                                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                                            .accentColor),
                                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                                .focusColor
                                                                .withOpacity(0.2))),
                                                    focusedBorder:
                                                        OutlineInputBorder(
                                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                color: Theme.of(
                                                                        context)
                                                                    .focusColor
                                                                    .withOpacity(
                                                                        0.5))),
                                                    enabledBorder:
                                                        OutlineInputBorder(
                                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                color: Theme.of(
                                                                        context)
                                                                    .accentColor
                                                                    .withOpacity(
                                                                        0.2))),
                                                    hintText:
                                                        S.S.of(context).flatNo,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                  child: CheckboxFormField(
                                                    context: context,
                                                    initialValue:
                                                        address.isDefault ?? false,
                                                    onSaved: (input) =>
                                                        address.isDefault = input,
                                                    title: Text(S.S
                                                        .of(context)
                                                        .make_default),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
            )
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create a bottom sheet and do widget tree analysis, you will find out its not part of this widget child where you created bottom sheet. So It's different `context` where you created provider and the bottom sheet is not its child so the context could not find the provider. To access the specific provider in bottom sheet, you need to explicitly pass the provider here. Check below example

```dart
var valueProvider = Provider.of<TitleDataNotifier>(context, listen: false);
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: valueProvider,
          child: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter state) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: BottomSheetWidget(valueProvider),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
  );
```

So inside the `BottomSheetWidget`, you can use `valueProvider` to get the required parameters.

Comment: what you have to pass inside Provider.of<> when you are assigning valueProvider variable  ?

Comment: I have Passed the Class, but still getting an error, Please can you show the example through my code above

Comment: You need to use ` Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false);`

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60575893/4788260)